# Delete all orphaned revisions from wp_posts in wordpress?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I want to delete all the revisions from wp_posts where the post it is a revision of no longer exists.

I imagine we would need more then one query then then also clean up wp_postmeta.

What is the best way to do this from phpmyadmin?

Comment: Not technically an answer as it doesn't use phpmyadmin, but I've used a plugin for this exact task: https://wordpress.org/plugins/rvg-optimize-database/ It's worked on 3 or 4 sites with no issues

Comment: @DavidAlsbright; thanks! I actually looked at this but it doesn't do what I need. It deletes ALL revisions that match a date range. I just want to get rid of the orphaned ones. Unless, am I missing something?